# Am I applying command pattern correctly?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, command-pattern

I'm currently working on a Unity project and I decided to use command pattern to manage the buttons of the interface among other things. I'm not sure if I'm applying the patter the way I should because I'm not using an invoker for example.

This is an example of the code I have:

```
public interface iCommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

```
public class GenerateCommand : iCommand
{
        private Generator _generator;
    private Slider _sliderWidth, _sliderHeight;

    public GenerateCommand(Generator generator, Slider sliderWidth, Slider sliderHeight)
    {
        this._generator = generator;
        this._sliderWidth = sliderWidth;
        this._sliderHeight = sliderHeight;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _generator.Destroy();
        _generator.SetWidth((int)_sliderWidth.value);
        _generator.SetHeight((int)_sliderHeight.value);
        _generator.Generate();
        _generator.Build();
    }
}
```

public class AppController : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Generator generator;
public Slider sliderWidth, sliderHeight;
public GameObject generatorController, playerController, UI, app, room, spawnLocation;


private iCommand _command;


void Start()
{
    generator = new DepthFirstSearchGenerator(room: room, spawnLocation: spawnLocation);
    Generate();
}

public void Generate()
{
    _command = new GenerateCommand(generator: generator, sliderWidth: sliderWidth, sliderHeight: sliderHeight);
    _command.Execute();
}
```

And then i call the Generate() function from the button when clicked.

Comment: I think the way you are using it you don't really need a command pattern at all .. it seems overcomplicating things. You usually do this if you a) want some sort of undo/redo/history support and/or b) want to centralize the execution of commands in a single place and e.g. add some additional behavior around it (again e.g. for a) a service that keep track of the history of all commands) and/or c) if only such central service has the required information to be passed into `Execute` as parameters

Comment: actually I don't really see why you would use multiple individual commands within a single click .. I would probably expect all those calls to be combined within one single `GenerateCommand`. You basically can achieve the same thing by using some mediator between the UI and the `Generator` which bundles and handles the calls by simply registering them as callbacks to your UI (goes into Model View Presenter pattern)

Comment: @derHugo I transformed the GenerateCommand making it just one command and I centralized all actions in the AppController class so I initialize all Objects I need in a single class instead of doing it in multiple different scripts.

Comment: still question is .. if you are not actually makin use o the command pattern regarding things like tracking the history etc ... what speaks against simply doing `public void Generate(){ var _generator = this.GetComponent<Generator>();  _generator.Destroy();
        _generator.SetWidth((int)_sliderWidth.value);
        _generator.SetHeight((int)_sliderHeight.value);
        _generator.Generate();
        _generator.Build(); }` ? .. or even have according method on `Generator` itself already handling all of these internally?

Comment: @derHugo The thing is I will have different generators but only one active at the time, with the AppController I can change the one generator whenever I want and the buttons will always call the same functions. So I need an external "agent" that invokes the internal methods. I think the system I created works really well and it is confortable to use. But I guess is kind of a custom command pattern hahaha

Comment: in that case I would probably pass in he current generator as a parameter to the command .. still command pattern only really makes a difference when apart from the command something else is being handled by your AppController ... for example after every command trigger an automatic save process .. or as mentioned keep track of history etc